# Alternative of Multisim or PSpice

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

I'd used `Multisim` and `PSpice` in windows for circuit simulation. But both softwares are unavailable for ubuntu. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ktechlab](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ktechlab/) is an alternative to Pspice. This software runs on Linux.

Edit :Try a software called geda

Comment: This is not available for 14.04.

Comment: Try a software called geda