# Regarding software installation

Tags: software-center

How can i install multisim ,proteus application used by Electrical and communication Department in Ubuntu 14.04Lts.

please send me some link how to install in command based or solution .,
please respond if it can be installed or any other softwares where i can make the work done of the same softwares mentioned above.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuEngineering#Electronics has some suggestions of alternatives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any alternative programs to Proteus available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/77399/are-there-any-alternative-programs-to-proteus-available)

Answer (score 0):

There are some related questions here on AskUbuntu:

- [Alternative of Multisim or PSpice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472026/alternative-of-multisim-or-pspice)
- [Are there any alternative programs to Proteus available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77399/are-there-any-alternative-programs-to-proteus-available)

Suggestions:

- Run these Windows programs on Ubuntu with wine. See [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-do-i-install-and-configure-wine)
- try gEDA:

> sudo apt-get install geda-gschem

- try ktechlab:

  [How to install ktechlab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116851/how-to-install-ktechlab)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to install VirtualBox and run your software's compatible windows(software that doesn't run in ubuntu) in the virtual machine.